Salesforce Base URL not working as expected
LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))
Above formula given https://lloydsreg-lex--partf01.sandbox.lightning.force.com/ on formula field on case object
 <td><a href="{! LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))}{!'/lightning/r/Case/'+relatedTo.Id+'/view'}">{!relatedTo.CaseNumber}</a></td> but this i used in HtmL template using VF compoenet it  retun https://Portal_lr.org url WHy?

I have tested email by using send test verify merge field its showing correct but when i recive email and click on link it navigate to portal URL
How its work diffrently in VF compoent and formula field in salesforce
